# send a message in a specific action namespace

Tags: ros, namespace, actionlib, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS community!

The Fibonacci Example works with my android-device & ubuntu combination. Now I adapted that example to my own purposes. It uses different messages now and the action server already exists and waits for new goal messages.

But the client is stuck at the line "sac.waitForServer();". I used rxgraph to check the problem and realized:

- my client publishes: "goal [Type: package_xyz/message_xyz]"
- the server subscribes to: "abc/goal [Type: package_xyz/message_xyz]"

So, both, the server and the client use the same message type, but the first part is different. I just can guess, that the first part is called "namespace"?

Therefore my question is: **How can I set the namespace of my client?**

I already discovered that I can create an actionClient by using "spec.buildSimpleActionClient("abc");" where "abc" is the namespace parameter. But that doesn't change anything in rxgraph and the client and the server still won't connect.

Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12818/send-a-message-in-a-specific-action-namespace/) by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2012-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution for setting the namespace! It has to be done when setting up the NodeConfiguration:

```
NodeConfiguration configuration = NodeConfiguration.createDefault();
configuration.setHost(host);
configuration.setMasterUri(uri);
NameResolver res = NameResolver.createFromString("/abc");
configuration.setParentResolver(res);
```

Nodes and topics created with this configuration will always have the prefix "/abc", e.g. "/abc/goal" which is exactly the behaviour i needed.

---

Originally posted by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) with karma: 77 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2